# Style changing automatically everyday with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have to create a 7 boxes with a some infos on it, and every boxes have to be in black and white. But each Box (for example Box number 1 with a Monday text on it) must be changed in own color automatically when we are on Monday (and another boxes in black and white) and the another boxes on Tuesday and ... have to be continued like that

i write down my codes

For example we are now on Tuesday, but will changed the text in purple , not that pic!

i think, this property (-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);) can be removed everyday day in JavaScript, but i dont know how!

can u help me pls to find a solution for that?
Tnx so much

```js
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "yellow";
weekday[1] = "red";
weekday[2] = "green";
weekday[3] = "purple";
weekday[4] = "orange";
weekday[5] = "white";
weekday[6] = "brown";

document.getElementById("test").style.color = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

```css
#test {
}

.img-test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 390px;
    object-fit: cover;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<section id="test">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
      <h2>Industrie</h2>
      <a class="position-relative d-block" href="" title="">
        <img class="img-fluid img-test d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_11.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
use date to get the day of the week and depend on it color your textbox

Comment: What attempts have you made, where did you get stuck? Can you write a pseudo-code attempt/description of how it might be implemented in a step-by-step way?

Comment: You can create 7 Boxes with HTML assining an ID to each of them. Then you write a short JavaScript function, which checks the current day. And with this result you can set the background of each box, as needed. That would be one possibility how to achieve this goal.

Comment: So the process is like this. You have a requirement. Change color of box depending on day of week. Good. Next thing is to ask yourself how do i know which day of the week it is. Good. Google ' get day of week javascript ' , find javascript Date object documentation. Find the ' getDay() ' method which returns the day of the week. With javasript add a class ' moday'  or ' tuesday ' and so on to the box you want depending on the result of getDay. Style that class in CSS. It's a max 60 minute job. Please take the time to do some research

Comment: why would he need setInterval ? as the javascript will get the getDay only when a user opens the website. SetInterval will be reset everytime the user opens the page.  Javascript cannot know when the function was called last time because you don't store the ' day ' anywhere. You could store the `lastUpdateDay` in API, then get it and check if getDay() !== lastUpdateDay then do the color update function. But otherwise you cannot know if currentDay differes from the llastUpdateDay. Or you could store it in localstorage, that might work but it's not ideal.

Comment: @MihaiT NVM, you're right the advice was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "yellow";
weekday[1] = "red";
weekday[2] = "green";
weekday[3] = "purple";
weekday[4] = "orange";
weekday[5] = "white";
weekday[6] = "brown";

document.getElementById(ELEMENT_ID).style.color = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

Comment: he gets it in ` weekday[d.getDay()]`

Comment: @Daweed that's worked but the text color just will be changed! i have to write down at the first my codes, then maybe we can finde a solution for it

html:

  <section id="test">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
      <h2>Industrie</h2>
      <a class="position-relative d-block" href="" title="">
        <img class="img-fluid img-test d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_11.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

Comment: css:  
#test {
}

.img-test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 390px;
    object-fit: cover;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

Comment: now my pic is in black and white but the text top of the pic is purple (weekday [3] )

Comment: i wanna every pic will be changed automatically in own color in a right day and another pic be in black and white

Comment: I think it depends on what element are you passing in. It is hard to tell without updated code. Maybe try different element?

Comment: now this .img-test with this property > -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);  is in black and white and just this property must be deleted automatically everyday in Java Script. but i dont know how, then i think that might be easy for u :)

Comment: @AmirTafkhimi since this question is closed, try editing it so I can see the problem detailed?

Comment: @AmirTafkhimi you have more than enough information on how to solve your problem. For eg you have the monday image with id `day-1` and then just add a class `todayImage` to the image which has the `id` of `day-${date.getDay()}` and in your css add the filter on all images except on the one that has `.todayImage` class.

Comment: @MihaiT i can understand that what u mean, but if i add filter on all images except on of them, its clear thats about just css.
how can i define that in Javascript that each pic will be chang automatically everyday
can u see my codes pls? i wrote down on the top and maybe u can edit that

Comment: @MihaiT its that problem that i don’t have more infos about Javascript because of that maybe i cant understand the functions so good like u :) sorry

Comment: well yes. It's mostly CSS. using `:not` pseudo selector. In javascript you just need to add the `todayImage` classname to the image depending on `date.getDay()` . I wrote you exactly what you need to do. HTML `<img id="day-1" ..... />` for monday image and so on. JS : document.getElementById(`day-${date.getDay()}`).classlist.add('today-image') . CSS : img:not(.today-image) { filter } . As a suggestion, if you want to do frontend stuff. Do some javascript tutorials. This is very very basic javascript-html-css interaction.